# While copying a directory structure with FileUtils.copyDirectory, How to modify the inside files content

Tags: java, file, filesystems

I'm copying a directory structure from one place to another place. it contains number of folders and files. By using `FileUtils.copyDirectory` I'm able to copy the folder structure along with files and folders. Internally while copying a file, I need to edit some data (common for all files). Copying and editing should be done at the same time. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

**Code:**

```
File source = new File("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\123");
File dest = new File("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\321");
try {
    FileUtils.copyDirectory(source, dest);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The internal subfolders contain JSON files where I need to replace a `String`.

**Example:**

```
 "text" : "@@ROLL_NUMBER@@" to  "text" : "13T95A0502"
```

The above JSON field is present in every file.

Comment: Looks like you have to walk the copy and replace that value in every file. Consider using [`java.nio`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) for that instead of `java.io` plus apache commons' `FileUtils`.

Comment: Take a look at FileVisitor class, it's for modifying file in the file tree. Maybe it would help you.